# Make the columnHeader as wide as the css column

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Thats what I tried:

http://codepen.io/helloworld/pen/BcjCJ

I want that each column has visually the same width as the column header.

At the moment a column header is a bit wider than a column just see the pen.

From where comes this "space" which makes the column header a bit wider than the column?

**UPDATE**

Just found out its the text which creates scrollbars on the "table"

Is it possible to add this scrollbar size to the FIRST column header width without using javascript maybe by a clever css3/SASS function? calc() whatever...

I can not spot any bad padding/margin.

**HTML**

```
<div id="gridHeader">     
      <div class="columnHeader">Monday</div>
      <div class="columnHeader">Tuesday</div>        
  </div>
  <div id="gridContent">

    <!-- Monday Column-->
    <div style="background:lightblue;" class="column">
      <!-- ko: foreach-->    
      <div class="row">1111111111111111111 11111111111111111111111111111111 111111111111111 11111111111111111111111111111111 111111111111111 11111111111111111111111111111111 111111111111111 11111111111111111111111111111111 111111111111111111111111111111111 111111111111111 11111111111111111111111111111111 111111111111111 111111111111111111111111111111111 111111111111111 11111111111111111111111111111111 111111111111111 11111111111111111111111111111111 111111111111111 11111111111111111111111111111111 111111111111111 1111111111111 11111111111111111111111111111111 111111111111111 11111111111111111111111111111111 111111111111111 11111111111111111111111111111111 111111111111111 11111111111111111111111111111111 111111111111111 111111111111111 1111111111111</div>

      <div class="row">2222222222222222222222222222222 2222222222222222222222222222 222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222 2222222222222222222222222222 222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222 2222222222222222222222222222 222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222 2222222222222222222222222222 222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222 2222222222222222222222222222 222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222 2222222222222222222222222222 222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222 2222222222222222222222222222 22222222222222222222222222222222222222 2222222222222222222222222222 222222222222222222222</div>
    </div>

    <!-- Tuesday Column-->
    <div style="background:green;" class="column">
        <!-- ko: foreach-->
      <div class="row">fsadffsfsfsd fsdsfdfsdfsadffsadffsfsfsd fsdsfdfsdfsadfsadfsadffsfsfsd fsdsfdfsdfsadfsadfsadffsfsfsd fsdsfdfsdfsadfsadfsadfffsadffsfsfsd   fsdsfdfsdfsadfsadfsadffsadfsadfsadfffsadffsfsfsd fsdsfdfsdfsadfsadfsadffsfsfsd fsdsfdfsdfsadfsadfsadffsfsfsd fsdsfdfsdfsadfsadfsadffsfsfsd  dffsfsfsd fsdsfdfsdfsadfsadfsadffsfsfsd fsdsfdfsdfsadfsadfsadffsfsfsd fsdsfdfsdfsadfsadsad</div>
      <div class="row">fsadffsfsfsd fsdsfdfsdfsadffsadffsfsfsd fsdsfdfsdfsadfsadfsadffsfsfsd fsdsfdfsdfsadfsadfsadffsfsfsd fsdsfdfsdfsadfsadfsadfffsadffsfsfsd fsdsfdfsdfsadfsadfsadffsfsfsd fsdsfdfsdfsadfsadfsadffsfsfsd fsdsfdfsdfsadfsadfsadffsfsfsd fsdsfdfsdfsadfsadfsadffsfsfsd fsdsfdfsdfsadfsadfdfsdfsadfsadfsadffsfsfsd fsdsfdfsdfsadfsadfsadffsfsfsd fsdsfdfsdfsadfsadfsadffsfsfsd fsdsfdfsdfsadfsadsad</div>
    </div>

  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.columnHeader{
  border:1px solid red;
  background:yellow;
}

.columnHeader, .column{
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;

  /* This causes that all headers have the same width independently from their content */
  width:100%;  
  font-weight:bold;
  font-size:1.2em;

}

#gridHeader{  
  display: flex; /* current version */
 /* This causes that all columns have the same width independently from their content */  
  width:100%;  
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;  
  position:fixed;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  height:50px;  
  background:gray;
}

#gridContent{  
  display: -webkit-box;
 /* This causes that all columns have the same width independently from their content */
  width:100%; 
  position:fixed;
  top:50px;
  left:0px; 
  bottom:0px;
  overflow-y:auto;
  overflow-x:hidden;
}

*{ 
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.row{
  height:200px;  /* fix this with flex that the equal height is taken*/

  overflow-y:auto;
  overflow-x:hidden;
  border:1px solid blue;
  background:orange;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve that problem you need to remove the overflow-x and overflow-y from your #gridContent and your .row class.

The scrollbars are making them not look align.